# Drag-to-disc CD or DVD writing software?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, burning, drag-and-drop

I just came to know about packet writing, which enables files to be written to disc one-by-one, instead of "burning" a whole disc all at once. After some initial searches all I've come up with is:

- Roxio Creator - includes [DirectCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag-to-Disc)
- Nero Suite - includes [InCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InCD)

I'm looking for a functional CD/DVD packet writing software for Windows, without the extra bloat.

Do you know of any?

Comment: I found a minimal drag and drop Disc burning app at last! See my answer. Its a new version of "Drive Letter Access" compatible with XP/Vista/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Burning]

**[Roxio Burn](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/dla/overview.html)** - drag and drop disc burning in an easy to use desktop widget. (XP, Vista, 7)

- Drag and drop files and folders directly to a recordable CD, DVD or Blu-ray Disc
- Files can burn across multiple discs
- Drop an .iso image onto the widget to burn, bootable discs supported
- Copy or Erase a disc

Answer (score 5):

Windows Vista's already got a nice CD Burner. If you use the Live File System Formatting, you can always add or remove files from your discs.

Comment: Yup. It's built into Windows these days.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Windows CD Burner, i know that it's not the best, but have this feature.

Comment: here is its link http://cdburnerxp.se/download